# Error: package or namespace load failed for 'export':

Tags: r

An error is shown when using

```
devtools::install_github("tomwenseleers/export")

** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'export':
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
  error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/rJava/libs/i386/rJava.dll':
LoadLibrary failure:   %1 is not a valid Win32 application
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
*** arch - x64
Warning: replacing previous import 'ReporteRs::renderFlexTable' by 'rtable::renderFlexTable' when loading 'export'
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386'
* removing 'C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/export'
In R CMD INSTALL
```

And I have tried everything I could find on stackflow,for example from [.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava' when installing a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29941797/onload-failed-in-loadnamespace-for-rjava-when-installing-a-package). And here is what I have tried so far :

1) set the JAVA HOME using

```
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_151') or
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre1.8.0_151')
```

2) add the `"--no-multiarch"` as :

```
devtools::install_github("tomwenseleers/export",INSTALL_opts="--no-multiarch")
```

3) quit R session and reopen R, re-download JAVA 8 and rJava

4) point out the jvm.dll path 
`Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_45\\bin\\client')`

I just don't understand how I could solve this...

Any idea would be helpful!